# extract IF multiline condition using python regexp

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract the condition of a if block in a .c file using python regexp. The string will be something like these:

```
if((x==z)&&(x<y))
```

or

```
if(x==9)
```

or

```
if((x==10) &&
   (y==9))
```

so there are possible 2 variations.

1. there may or may not be nested brackets inside.
2. multiple sub condition can be in different line.

Expected output is:
the complete condition inside the outermost bracket.

I have written this code to detect single line condition, but stuck at multiline condition.

```
import re
with open("code.txt", "r") as ins:
array = []
for line in ins:
    array.append(line)
    trimLine = line.lstrip();
    trimLine = trimLine.rstrip();


    result = re.findall(r'if', trimLine)
    if result != []:
        print (re.search( "\((.*)\)" ,trimLine).group(1))
```

TIA for any kind of guidance.

Comment: For more complex cases (inline if, function call in condition with multiline arguments, ...) you will need more complex technology than regexp, see https://github.com/eliben/pycparser

Comment: i have looked in that one previously. Problem was my existing code base was in C++. pycparser don't support that. Also it was way much complex that what I wanted to do. My goal is to extract the control flow of  a single function ( if, else, elseif,switch-case-default, break, continue, loops) without the hassle of doing preprocessing. Just basic summary is what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

by default **.** do not match new line.
you should use re.DOTALL so it will match new line too.

[image]